# How to display local json file with key value data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this json file and I want to display in a ListView Widget only the key of this data.
Something  like in [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiGNN.png). I'm new in flutter.

```
{
  "cards": [
      {
      "name": {
        "Title Card 1": 3,
        "Title Card 2": 1,
        "Title Card 3": 1,
        "Title Card 4": 2,
        "Title Card 5": 1        
      },
      "authors": {
        "Author John": 2,
        "Author Carl": 1,
        "Author Ben": 5
      },
      "language": {
        "en": 74,
        "fr": 11
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Comment: create model for your json using this https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ and call it as map/object

Answer (score 0):

try in this way...

```
// Fetch content from the json file
      Future<void> readJson() async {
        final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
        final data = await json.decode(response);
        setState(() {
          _items = data["items"];
        });
      }
```

> And Display in this way

```
_items.isNotEmpty
                ? Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Text(_items[index]["id"]),
                            title: Text(_items[index]["name"]),
                            subtitle: Text(_items[index]["description"]),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container()
```

for more info check out this link : [Json Data Display](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-flutter/)